# Symlinked file transfer rate in WinSCP

Tags: symbolic-link, sftp, winscp

I have found that downloading a file in WinSCP via a symlink to the file, as opposed to the file itself, reduces the transfer speed by a factor of ~8.  I'll list the various conditions I've tested this on at the end, suffice to say it seems quite persistent.  I'm not able to find reference to this issue in the [bug tracker](https://winscp.net/tracker/), nor in any of the similar posts I've reviewed here on SU.  Is this a new bug?

**Conditions**

- Observed this pattern for several months
- Have tried transferring from and to (at least) two different computers for most tests
- That means 2 "from" computers and 2 "to" computers
- Always on a Windows machine downloading from a Linux machine
- All computers on different networks
- All connections are wired
- All transfer speeds are <25% of connection capacity, usually <10%
- Using large files
- Latest v5.15.1 (build 9407) WinSCP
- Default WinSCP (SFTP) transfer options

**Tests**

- Transfer of individual file vs. symlinked file
- Transfer of folder with files vs. folder with symlinked files
- Performance tests run simultaneously on the same systems and files to minimize extraneous variables
- Verified `psftp`, PuTTY's SFTP upon which WinSCP is built, does not exhibit issue
- Verified `sftp` command in Cygwin, does not exhibit issue
- Verified scp-based connection in WinSCP does not exhibit issue
- Verified transfer speeds are stable (i.e. self-consistent) across tests for a given set of conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of WinSCP (5.16) is not considering a target file size when employing download optimization strategies. Hence the low transfer rate.

The next version will do:
https://winscp.net/tracker/1747

---

*Btw, WinSCP is not using psftp SFTP code. Only PuTTY SSH code.*

Comment: So this slowdown is because WinSCP is grabbing overly small packets or something?  Thanks for the SFTP/SSH comment, note that WinSCP's "[slow FAQ](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_slow)" mentions PSFTP, which is why I presumed that was the the correct point of comparison.

Comment: Yes, small packets and short packet window/queue.